# Connect Azure Databricks with JDBC driver and Azure AD token of the Service Principal

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

The use case I am working is to connect Databricks cluster using jdbc driver from external web service and query tables.

The connection string explained over document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi#--jdbc-driver) mentioned two tokens to be used and they are azure ad token and PAT token.

The confusion is, why do we need PAT token required here along with Azure AD token? Is AAD token is not enough to authenticate?

I am able to connect through PAT token (my user account) with jdbc driver but using service principal make it robust.

Comment: please share error you are facing?

Comment: @PratikLad  The question was basically to know the importance of PAT token along with Azure AD token and why Azure AD is not enough to get through jdbc connection..It is not related to any code error or exception.

Comment: You can use personal access token OR an Azure Active Directory token. Either one will work.

Comment: Thanks @Kombajnzbożowy..I stumbled upon below jdbc string setup as mentioned over document:                                                                                                        
            String url = "jdbc:spark://<Server Hostname>;HttpPath=<Http Path>;TransportMode=http;SSL=1";
Properties p = new java.util.Properties();
p.put("AuthMech", "11");
p.put("Auth_Flow", "0");
p.put("Auth_AccessToken", "<aad-token>");
p.put("PWD", "<persoanl-access-token>");
DriverManager.getConnection(url, p);

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to provide AAD token that you generated for your service principal - you don't need to provide PAT.  You just need to set correct value for `AuthMeth` (11 instead of 3), set `Auth_AccessToken` to value of your AAD token, and `Auth_Flow` to `0`.  Here is [complete example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/simba-jdbc-aad-token) of accessing DBSQL via JDBC with AAD token generated for service principal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AD token is enough to authenticate the connection to Azure Databricks, but you also need a PAT to authorize the specific actions that the connection can perform within the Databricks workspace.

In other words, PAT can be used to authorize a user to run a specific notebook to read or write data to a specific cluster.

**I reproduce same in my environment with PAT token . I got this output.**

> Note: Make sure to install **Databricks SQL Connect** :  `pip install databricks-sql-connector`

**Code:**

```
import os
from databricks import sql

conn = sql.connect(
    server_hostname = "adb-xxxxxxx.12.azuredatabricks.net",
    http_path = "/sql/1.0/warehouses/xxxxx",
    access_token = "dapiaxxxxxxxxxxxx78e7f")

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * from <table_name>")
display(cursor.fetchall())

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: In other way we can say, if the Service principal has proper authorization(like owner,contributor or admin role) then PAT is not required!!

Comment: @krishcoolster, That's correct. you can use the Azure AD token for authentication and the PAT is not required.

Comment: The PAT is typically used where you need to access Databricks resources that the service principal does not have access to.